# Unable to call an instance method from Clojure.

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, clojure-java-interop

I'm completely new to Java and clojure. But with previous experience in common lisp, I thought I would give clojure a try. I'm unable to figure out few very basic things.

This is the actual Java code.

```
import syntaxtree.*;
import visitor.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        Node root = new MicroJavaParser(System.in).Goal();
        System.out.println("Program parsed successfully");
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the outcome is as expected.

```
└──╼ java Main < ../input/Factorial.java 
Program parsed successfully
```

In Clojure I tried this :

```
(ns clj-assign2.core)

(defn -main
  []
  (def root
    (.Goal
     (MicroJavaParser. (. System in))))
  (println "Successfully parsed"))
```

But when this code is run, the following exception is raised :

```
└──╼ lein run < ../assign2/input/Factorial.java 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: Goal for class MicroJavaParser
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:300)
    at clj_assign2.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:7)
< --- snipped --- >
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the signature for the Goal method?

Comment: What's the visibility of the Goal method?

Comment: It's not possible to tell from what you have posted. Maybe, Goal is variadic, which might cause this. Try printing out all the methods in MicroJavaParser using reflection, try printing out the output of getClass. Or try it to get it working on classes in java.lang so that other people can try your code.  Incidentally, using a def inside a defn like this is generally not a good idea!

Comment: The mistake was on my end. I didn't have the source code for the parser. I didn't realize that `Goal()` function in the call `new MicroJavaParser(System.in).Goal()` was actually static. Well, Clojure does a better job here, you always know the kind of call from the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing an import statement in your clojure program?